# jQuery width returns pixels instead of %

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
 <div class="ui-progress" style="width: 10%;">

 console.log($(this).width());
```

returns width in pixels not %. How do I get the percentage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var width = $('.ui-progress').width();
var parentWidth = $('.ui-progress').offsetParent().width();
var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
```

OR

```
var width = ( 100 * parseFloat($('.ui-progress').css('width')) / parseFloat($('.ui-progress').parent().css('width')) ) + '%';
```

#### Note

You can use `.offsetParent()` if parent of `.ui-progress` has CSS `position:absolute`.

Comment: Excellent. It's not 100% accurate, but it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a width in pixels because that's how the percentage is interpreted by a browser. It may be displayed as a percent in your CSS, but it gets turned into a pixel value when displayed by the browser.

console.log($(this).attr("style"));

Answer (score 0):

You can get % if the div is hidden. When the div is hidden $(selector).width() returns percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

```
var xdom = $('.ui-progress')[0];
var percentWidth = xdom.style['width'];
```

Or

```
var percent_width=xdom.style.width;
```